# How to properly run tests on github using pytest?

Tags: python, pytest, github-actions

I wrote a program in haskell and would like to write tests for it using pytest. I would also like to set up a workflow on github. So here is the code for the tests:

```py
def path_to_bin():
    stream = os.popen('cabal exec which haskell-lab4-exe')
    bin_p = stream.read()
    bin_p = bin_p.replace('\n', '')
    return bin_p

def test_1():
    os.popen(path_to_bin() +' --use ./test_files/left.use --dox ./test_files/left.dox')
    time.sleep(3)
    file1 = open("./python/test/expected_results/lu_ld_diff.md", "r")
    file2 = open("diff.md", "r")
    expected = file1.read()
    res = file2.read()
    assert(res == expected)


def test_2():
    os.popen(path_to_bin() +' --use ./test_files/right.use --dox ./test_files/left.dox')
    time.sleep(3)
    file1 = open("./python/test/expected_results/ru_ld_diff.md", "r")
    file2 = open("diff.md", "r")
    expected = file1.read()
    res = file2.read()
    assert(res == expected)
```

So, my program should compare the 2 files and output the result in `diff.md`
Locally the tests work fine, but on github the first test always gets bogged down by this:

```
E       FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'diff.md'
python/test/test.py:16: FileNotFoundError
24
----------------------------- Captured stderr call -----------------------------
25
/bin/sh: 1: Resolving: not found
```

I tried swapping tests, but the problem is the same, the first test always crashes, the others always pass. I tried to increase the delay after the execution of the command to generate, but it does not help.

So, I would like to know why this is possible?

Comment: Why are you using `pytest`? Cabal can run test suites itself.

Comment: Instead of the `os.popen()` and `time.sleep()` combination, you can simply use [subprocess.run](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run). It'll take care of the wait itself. From that error, it's evident that the `diff.md` has not been created. You might need to check with `pwd` and `ls` commands too whether you're loading it from the right place.